# Drop operation not being applied over two combined datasets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have combined the training and test sets in a list so that I can perform simultaneous operations.
However, the first operation I tested is not working as it should, unless I use "inplace = True"

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('house_train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('house_test.csv')
combine = [train_df, test_df]

for x in combine:
    x = x.drop(columns = ['Id'], axis = 1)

train_df.head()
```

The column 'Id' isn't getting dropped unless "inplace" is applied, which isn't the case outside of the combined list.

Comment: Why do you want to assign it instead of using inplace? because in that case u need to assign it to combine[x] = ....

Answer (score 1):

In your case assign it back

```
for x in range(len(combine)):
    combine['x'] = combine['x'].drop(columns=['Id'], axis=1)
```